# Unity Application Crashes when Video player have non-video URL

Tags: unity

I wanna make an Online video player that player can set link.
application crashes on exit when link is non-video.
it happened even in editor and editor crashes when I want to exit editor.!!!

I use 2018.4.21f
what happened and how can I fixed?
is it a bug???

```
//---------------simple code
public void Start(){
        //init
        vplayer = GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        vplayer.url = "http://www.google.com"; //this is a valid format sample link that is non-video
        vplayer.errorReceived += OnError;
        vplayer.prepareCompleted += OnPreComplete;
}

public void PlayButton(){
        vplayer.Prepare();
}
//--------
void OnPreComplete(VideoPlayer videoPlayer){
        vplayer.Play();
}
void OnError(VideoPlayer videoPlayer,string msg){
        print("error: " + msg);
}
```

I got this error :
windowsVideoMedia error 0x00d0035 while reading http://www.google.com

Comment: What kind of error message do you get when you reproduce this crash in editor or in a development build with logging?

Comment: windowsVideoMedia error 0x00d0035 while reading http://thisisTest.com

Comment: Can you show us your code where you try to use this link? Have you tried wrapping it in a try/catch block to handle the error safely?

Comment: @DMGregory - the code is so simple. I use videoplayer.prepare() with "prepareCompleted" event. and handle errors by "errorReceived" event. I got recevie many of error...but that freeze is just happen when I used http invalid link.
I tried "try/catch" too .. but still freezes at Quit.
...
for try my code just add videoplayer component and set [http://test.com](link) as URL. play video player,stop program and try to close Unity Editor!!

Comment: Great, now add that code to your question.

Comment: error is obvious! your link http://www.google.com isn't video! try again with video link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Test this Problem on Unity 2019.3.2
make a Video player with url that filled http://google.com
that's ok and did not freeze when I closed unity
...
but try this test on 2018.4.21 and unity freezes when I click on close button!!!

This is a BUG on 2018!

Comment: It's not clear that this Answer contains a solution to the problem. Did you mean to share this as additional information in your Question instead?

Comment: Why?...
I found a Solution of this bug

Comment: "Upgrade to 2019" is the solution you want to propose then?

Comment: Yeah ... becuse I searched for 3 days why my unity Editor and my application freezes when I want to close it ... I try many of solutions ... ask many of unity Programmers who used 2018 version...but still nothing to solve my problem... unitil one of my friends said test on 2019 version...and my problem is solved